# Python Select Interpreter not appearing in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio, virtualenv

I'm currently trying venv in VS Code but when I try to select the Interpreter with (Ctrl + Shift + P) it won't appear any option whatsoever. I tried writing in the Preferences: Open Default Settings JSON with no success.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to reinstall python
2. Reinstall the VSCode python plugin to resync things.

Answer (score 0):

1. Close your VsCode
2. Re-open it again

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).